# Using FreeTDS to connect to Azure SQL server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, azure, pyodbc

I designed a python script that does something and then writes to a Azure SQL server. Originally, I wrote the script on a windows machine and everything works great. Now I want to deploy the script on raspberry pis in the field. Where i'm having the hiccup is trying to get the pi to write to the SQL server. I am using FreeTDS as my driver for pyodbc, and my .ini files and the config file are as show below:

**odbcinst.ini**

```
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsS.so
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1
usagecount=1
```

**odbc.ini**

```
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = Azure cloud SQL server
Trace = no
ServerName = azure
database = main
TDS_Version = 7.0
```

**freetds.conf**

```
[azure]
        host = ************.database.windows.net
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
        instance = MSSQLSERVER
```

**python method**

```
def writeData():
server = '***************.database.windows.net'
        database = 'main'
        username = '****'
        password = '************'
        driver = '{FreeTDS}'

        with pyodbc.connect(
                'DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    "UPDATE dbo.server_ips SET ip_address = ?, port = ?, DateTime= ? WHERE server = 1;", (external_ip, port, datetime.now()))

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I have tried searching for answers but have come up empty so far.

Comment: `TDS_Version = 7.0` seems an odd choice. v7.0 is from SQL Server 7.0 days, not even this millennium. Have you tried `TDS_Version = 7.4`?

Comment: Just tried that, same issue.

Comment: Run `tsql -C` at a command prompt and verify that either `OpenSSL` or `GnuTLS` is enabled.

Comment: GnuTLS is shows 'yes', OpenSSL shows 'no'

Comment: Your odbcinst.ini is missing the `[FreeTDS]` line at the top.

Comment: Can you connect via `tsql -S azure -U sa -P _whatever_` …?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that writing to an azure sql server is not supported on ARM yet. I'm sure it will be soon considering windows 11 works on ARM processors.

Comment: The strange thing is that an Azure SQL Server is almost exactly like a normal SQL Server so it's curious that it isn't supported. You should be able to connect on port 1433 using SQL authentication exactly like any other SQL Server